# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>' when trying to concatenate Excel files

Tags: python, pandas

My question might be outdated but I'm sure it's not a duplicated one and sorry if it is !

I'm trying to concatenate some Excel files (stored in a folder) by using [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) but I keep getting errors, like the one shown below :

##### CODE :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def concat_excel(folder, ws=None):

    data = []

    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        current_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder, f), sheet_name=ws, dtype=str)
        current_df['Filename'] = f.split('.')[0]
        data.append(current_df)

    df = pd.concat(data, axis=0)

    return df

concat_excel(r'test\myfolder')
```

##### ERROR :

> ------> df = pd.concat(data)
>
> **TypeError**: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only
> Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Do you know how to fix this, please ?
Feel free to propose any better way for doing this..
Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround !
I'm adding it here, maybe it will be helpful for people who may face the same issue :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def concat_excel(folder, ws=None):
    data = []
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        temp = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder, f), sheet_name=ws, dtype=str))
        temp['Filename'] = f.split('.')[0] #to get rid of the file's entension
        data.append(temp)
    df = pd.concat(data)
    return df

concat_excel(r'test\myfolder')
```